# Is it possible to set linear gradient to the part of the HTML element that is outside viewport?

Tags: html, css, background-image, linear-gradients

### Is it possible to set a linear gradient to the part of the background of `<html>` element that is typically off screen and out of viewport, but can be "brought in to view" momentarily by trying to scroll past the limit in any of the 4 directions?

---

I am trying to make the color outside the viewport match my site color.   This way, when the user is at top of page and tries to scroll higher, on some browsers, the space that is shown and is typically white will match the color of my site.

I want to do the same thing for the bottom of site if user tries to scroll past bottom.

If I set  element's `background-color` to red, this works perfectly, and all the white color outside viewport, top f page, bottom of page, as well as left and right, will now be painted red instead of default white.

Problem is, my header and footer are different colors, so I need to use a linear-gradient.  When I use a gradient, for example:

```
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f8593a), to(#000));
```

```
 background: linear-gradient(#f8593a, #000) no-repeat;
```

it simply doesn't show up.

**Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible?**

---

**UPDATE**

[Test Case jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamandrebulatov/y7fqh8z5/2/)

Best I can do in a jsFiddle. (PS: if someone knows of a way to create a fiddle like this without jsFiddle's panels, so the actual Chrome pulling down can be tested, please suggest.)

The difference between this example and live behavior is that in the example, you can't drag the iFrame window past its boundary, thereby revealing that `out of viewport part of .'  However, the blue background-color here should represent that same area here.  And as can be seen, the color goes to that area without any extra work, while the linear-gradient is treated as an image and stays within some bounds.

Comment: You could try setting the background-size to something bigger than 100%. But my gut feeling says this is hugely browser dependent, so which browser and which platform are you targeting?

Comment: It's for webkit only, as I only see that white space outside the viewport on either Chrome or Safari.  Can't get linear gradient to work on either.  Tried extra paddings, negative margins with overflow, pseudo elements, but nothing so far.

Comment: If it's really important that this works the way you want, you could put in some JavaScript that changes the html's background color to either the header's or the footer's, depending on whether you are scrolling up or down.

Comment: May be changing background-attachment ?

Comment: First of all, don't use the ancient WebKit syntax. Both Chrome and Safari switched away from the syntax in your example at least 5 years ago! The current syntax is `background: linear-gradient(#f8593a, #000)`. As for the actual problem, could you create a reduced test case with just the header, footer and background on html element?

Comment: You're right, the old markup is not only obsolete, but also a nightmare compared to the new standard, thank you.  Test case added.

Comment: Though the JS solution is viable, I'd much rather prefer to do this with CSS only.  It's not important enough for JS, particularly if the only way to do it is by watching the scroll event.  Thank you tho.